# How can I delete files with PowerShell without confirmation?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the below PowerShell script to work using Task Scheduler. The problem is that it wont delete any files.

When I run it manually it needs a confirmation before deleting files.

```
Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want
 to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

How can I edit this script to delete files without any confirmation so I can run it using Task Scheduler?

```
#----- define parameters -----#
#----- get current date ----#
$Now = Get-Date
#----- define amount of days ----#
$Days = "10"
#----- define folder where files are located ----#
$TargetFolder = "D:\Shares\Downloads\TV\AutoDL"
#----- define extension ----#
$Extension = "*.*"
#----- define LastWriteTime parameter based on $Days ---#
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)

#----- get files based on lastwrite filter and specified folder ---#
$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}

foreach ($File in $Files) 
{
    if ($File -ne $NULL)
    {
        write-host "Deleting File $File" -ForegroundColor "DarkRed"
        Remove-Item $File.FullName | out-null
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "No more files to delete!" -foregroundcolor "Green"
    }
}
```

Comment: Powershell be like, false needs a $ except when it don't.

Answer (score 58):

```
Remove-Item foldertodelete -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
```

works for me.

Comment: A gotcha... I believe the item/object is a folder/directory, that also contains files, then not including `-Recurse` while including `-Confirm:$false` will result in a confirmation.  Take a closer look at the confirmation as it begins like `The item at <some-folder-pathname> has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified.` something about the missing `-Recurse` switch.

Comment: Why is it -confirm:$false here?    When I test:

try { Remove-Item .\bin -Confirm:False } catch{ }  

Does not confirm.   

try { Remove-Item .\bin -Confirm:$false } catch{ }

does confirm.  Powershell sure be shifty and weird.

Comment: @Warren P When you omit the `$` PS throws a ParameterBindingException, which you catch in you line of code. And sure, if it throws, it doesn't ask for confirmation...

Comment: -Confrim:$false is misleading,... the default is false, the problem is not the -Confirm it is the -Recurse (only the -Recurse)

Answer (score 21):

You need to add `-Confirm:$false` to the `Remove-Item` command to override the default confirmation behaviour. Failing that, try adding `-Force`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me for some reason when there are folders present.

Comment: Try this  -->

 try { Remove-Item .\bin -Confirm:False } catch{ }

Comment: This answer is 100% wrong x2.
it is neither the -Confirm swtich not the -Force switch... -Confrim:$false is misleading,... the default is false, the problem is not the -Confirm it is the -Recurse (only the -Recurse)

Answer (score 18):

In my opinion `Remove-Item -Path "C:\Temp\FolderToDelete" -Confirm:$false -Force` should just work without *any* prompt. But it doesn't.

To delete the whole folder and everything in it *without* any prompt, I had to use GCI and go up a level. So instead of:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\FolderToDelete" | Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$false -Force
```

Which deletes everything inside FolderToDelete, but not the parent folder.

To delete the parent folder and everything in it without a prompt, I did:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\" -Directory -Filter "FolderToDelete" | Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$false -Force
```

Note the trailing '\' in `-Path C:\Temp\`.

HTH

Comment: Agree with your -Recurse. For me Remove-Item was always asking the prompt cos I had * to end of path. Thanks.

Comment: Same as the other answers.
the sentiment here is correct by using Get-ChildItem and piping it into Remove-Item but still...
-Confrim:$false is misleading,... the default is false, the problem is not the -Confirm it is the -Recurse (only the -Recurse)

Answer (score 7):

It says

> Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?

Try: 
`Remove-Item ./folderToDelete -Force -Recurse`

Comment: can you please elaborate this answer.

Comment: Yes. What I meant to say is that if the prompt says that you need to confirm since the recurse switch parameter is missing, you should add the recurse parameter.

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER!, ironically it is the answer where someone has asked for elaboration, when it tells exactly what the situation is.
additionally suggesting the -Force switch too.
Great no mention of the -Confirm switch, so perfect answer!

UPVOTED!

Answer (score 5):

Delete a files folder\subfolders on `D:\FOLDER` (my example below), any files that older than 30 days.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\FOLDER\" -Recurse |? {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -confirm:$false -Verbose
```

The `-Force -Confirm:$false` guarantees that you don't have to press `Y` or `A` every time it deletes a file or folder. The `-Verbose` displays what is being deleted.

Comment: Same as the other answers... -Confrim:$false is misleading,... the default is false, the problem is not the -Confirm it is the -Recurse (only the -Recurse) –

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your script like it:

1. Use `-file` with `Get-Childitem` command
2. Not necessary to have a `$Now` variable
3. Use alias for your where (better visibility)
4. Your `if` must be out for check if no files
5. Add `-Force` to your `Remove-Item` command
6. Extension are not necessary if you use `'\*.*'`

Code ratified:

```
$Days = "10"
#----- define folder where files are located ----#
$TargetFolder = "D:\Shares\Downloads\TV\AutoDL"
#----- define LastWriteTime parameter based on $Days ---#
$LastWrite = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)

#----- get files based on lastwrite filter and specified folder ---#
$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Recurse -file | Where LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"

if ($Files -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "No more files to delete!" -foregroundcolor "Green"
}
else
{
   $Files | %{
   write-host "Deleting File $_" -ForegroundColor "DarkRed"
   Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force   | out-null
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I`ll give it a try. Will this also delete empty subfolders? My last script left all the empty subfolders behind.

Comment: Not simple and not correct!
Same as the other answers... -Confirm:$false is misleading,... the default is false, the problem is not the -Confirm it is the -Recurse (only the -Recurse) – –

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Get-ChildItem -Path "FolderToDelete" -Directory -recurse | where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $(get-date).Adddays(-7)} | Remove-Item -recurse -force

Comment: UP Voted, even though it could be given more content. because it is more correct than the rest of the answers with high scores.