# Why would Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Remove-Item work?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I've seen on a lot of places (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45210403/4399840), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-6), or [here](https://serverfault.com/a/199994)) where people suggest to use

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "Some path" -Recurse | Remove-Item
```

to recursively delete a directory, but why would this work?

When I run `Get-ChildItem -Path "foo" -Recurse | % { "$_" }`, I see directories were listed first, and then files follows.
It shows something like this:

```
1st_child_directory
2st_child_directory
...
1st_file_in_foo
2nd_file_in_foo
...
1st_file_in_1st_child_directory
2st_file_in_1st_child_directory
...
1st_file_in_2st_child_directory
...
```

And so on.

If these get piped into `Remove-Item` in the same order, then `Remove-Item` would remove directories first (which are still non-empty), and then remove files inside directories (but directories should already been removed), and this is a bit counter-intuitive... 
So why would `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Remove-Item` work, and how does it work?

Comment: Your examples have either the `-Force` parameter applied or use an extension `*.csv` which folders rarely have.

Comment: You can find out: Create some sample directories and files and run the command, and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a confirmation prompt, I had to use -recurse with remove-item:

```
get-childitem -recurse foo | remove-item -verbose -recurse

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "C:\users\admin\foo\dir1".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\users\admin\foo\dir1\file1".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "C:\users\admin\foo\dir2".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\users\admin\foo\dir2\file2".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "C:\users\admin\foo\dir3".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\users\admin\foo\dir3\file3".
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when the directory "Some path" contains only files or empty sub directories.

At least some of the articles you linked to have been updated since to ensure that:

- either the `Get-ChildItem` command returns only files
- the option `-Recurse` was added to the `Remove-Item` command